# Unique Values Select Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking to get unique values for woo.si_number and stm.serial_number. I am successful if I remove  "join stock stm on stm.pnm_auto_key = pnm.pnm_auto_key" but I need to retrieve the si_number.  Below is the code:

```
select woo.si_number, pnm.pn,cmp.company_name, wwt.description, stm.serial_number
from WO_OPERATION woo join parts_master pnm on woo.pnm_auto_key = pnm.pnm_auto_key
                      join companies cmp on cmp.cmp_auto_key = woo.cmp_auto_key
                      join wo_work_type wwt on wwt.wwt_auto_key = woo.wwt_auto_key
                      join stock stm on stm.pnm_auto_key = pnm.pnm_auto_key
where pnm.pn = '5A3307-7' AND
      stm.serial_number like 'BNG%' AND
      wwt.description = 'OVERHAULED'
                 order by woo.si_number
```

Jeff

---

Edit:

Actual output:

| si_number | pn | company_name | description | serial_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 166181 | 5A3307-7 | Westjet | OVERHAULED | BNG0776 |
| 166181 | 5A3307-7 | Westjet | OVERHAULED | BNG0776 |
| 166181 | 5A3307-7 | Westjet | OVERHAULED | BNG10014 |
| 166181 | 5A3307-7 | Westjet | OVERHAULED | BNG10014 |
| 166181 | 5A3307-7 | Westjet | OVERHAULED | BNG10014 |
| 166181 | 5A3307-7 | Westjet | OVERHAULED | BNG10014 |
| 166181 | 5A3307-7 | Westjet | OVERHAULED | BNG10023 |

Expected output:

| si_number | pn | serial_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 166181 | 5A3307-7 | BNG0776 |

Comment: Did you try SELECT DISTINCT ...?

Comment: I did but not really clear on the syntax.  It still created the same results.

Comment: Basically you should provide sample data and expected output. Given the number of tables - let's try with output generated from your statement - and what you actually expect instead. (If you get more than just a few rows, it should not be necessary to provide the full result set - just a sample of relevant rows...)

Comment: 166181 5A3307-7 Westjet OVERHAULED BNG0776
166181 5A3307-7 Westjet OVERHAULED BNG0776
166181 5A3307-7 Westjet OVERHAULED BNG10014
166181 5A3307-7 Westjet OVERHAULED BNG10014
166181 5A3307-7 Westjet OVERHAULED BNG10014
166181 5A3307-7 Westjet OVERHAULED BNG10014
166181 5A3307-7 Westjet OVERHAULED BNG10023

Comment: Results looking for:

Comment: 166181 I 5A3307-7 I BNG0776 I 16618

Comment: Don't provide data and expected results in comments. [Edit] your question and provide the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data and include the expected output in the question as well.

Comment: You select five columns, but expect to see three in the results? How come? And by what rule do you decide for serial number BNG0776? Why not BNG10014? Why not BNG10023?

Answer (score 1):

Query by adding the DISTINCT to get unique values for woo.si_number and stm.serial_number while still joining the table. By adding distinct only the unique will be returned after the query is executed : -

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  si_number,
  pn,
  company_name,
  description,
  serial_number
FROM
  (SELECT
    woo.si_number,
    pnm.pn,
    cmp.company_name,
    wwt.description,
    stm.serial_number
  FROM
    WO_OPERATION woo
  JOIN
    parts_master pnm ON woo.pnm_auto_key = pnm.pnm_auto_key
  JOIN
    companies cmp ON cmp.cmp_auto_key = woo.cmp_auto_key
  JOIN
    wo_work_type wwt ON wwt.wwt_auto_key = woo.wwt_auto_key
  JOIN
    stock stm ON stm.pnm_auto_key = pnm.pnm_auto_key
  WHERE
    pnm.pn = '5A3307-7' AND
    stm.serial_number LIKE 'BNG%' AND
    wwt.description = 'OVERHAULED') AS subquery
ORDER BY
  si_number;
```

Comment: Thanks Venkat but the results return duplicate si_numbers.

Comment: @jeff check the updated query.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your expected output is incomplete, the following query should return the expected result:

```
select distinct woo.si_number, pnm.pn, stm.serial_number
from WO_OPERATION woo join parts_master pnm on woo.pnm_auto_key = pnm.pnm_auto_key
                      join companies cmp on cmp.cmp_auto_key = woo.cmp_auto_key
                      join wo_work_type wwt on wwt.wwt_auto_key = woo.wwt_auto_key
                      join stock stm on stm.pnm_auto_key = pnm.pnm_auto_key
where pnm.pn = '5A3307-7' AND
      stm.serial_number = 'BNG0776' AND
      wwt.description = 'OVERHAULED'
order by woo.si_number
```

- `DISTINCT` removes the duplicate rows.
- If only one specific `serial_number` is expected - don't use wildcards.

Comment: Thanks Abecee but the result has many duplicate serial_numbers.

Comment: @Jeff Is my edit to your question correct regarding actual and expected output? Did you change from `LIKE` to `=`? Otherwise you might be fooled by trailing blanks - compare [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/104d3/1).

Answer (score 0):

You want one result row per si number and pn. So aggregate your data by these two columns (via `GROUP BY`). It is not clear by what rule you want to pick the serial number per si number and pn. In below example I take the minimum serial number.

```
select woo.si_number, pnm.pn, min(stm.serial_number) as serial_no
from wo_operation woo 
join parts_master pnm on pnm.pnm_auto_key = woo.pnm_auto_key
join stock stm on stm.pnm_auto_key = pnm.pnm_auto_key
where pnm.pn = '5A3307-7'
and stm.serial_number like 'BNG%' 
and woo.wwt_auto_key = 
(
  select wwt.wwt_auto_key
  from wo_work_type wwt
  where wwt.description = 'OVERHAULED'
)
group by woo.si_number, pnm.pn
order by woo.si_number;
```

Comment: Thanks Thorston but the results produce only one serial_number.  Jeff

Comment: What do you mean? There should be one result row per si_number and pn that match the criteria. For each such result row you get one serial number. So,m how is your result different from what you expect? Do you expect to get more si_number / pn combinations? Or what else?

Comment: Hi Thorsten,  I am only expecting the correct serial_number for the correct si_number.

Comment: Okay. And what is the correct serial_number? I asked you that question in the request comments yesterday and mentioned the lack of a rule in my answer. So, again: by what rule do you want to decide for the serial_number? I am taking the minimum serial_number in my query. This doesn't seem to be what you want, so what do you want instead?

Comment: Each si_number  has a different serial_number.  This just returned the same serial_number for all of the si_numbers.

Comment: No. Your data model allows multiple serial_numbers per si_number, and the "Actual output" in your request proves that. If you expect your criteria (pn = '5A3307-7', description = 'OVERHAULED') to return different serial_numbers for the si_numbers, then your original query is already off, as you see from your own result. Look at it, and I am pretty sure that you will find the serial_number my query returns for all the si_numbers in your query result, too.